# Can I know what is the name of the parameter that passed to the function?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If I call to the some function in bash , for example: `func ${a}` so exists way so that I will know what is the name of the variable that i passed with it the value to the function? (in this case: `a`)?

I know that it's not makes sense (because we can also call to this function without variable, for example: `func blabla` but my question is if exists way to know what is the name of the variable that passed (if the value passed via variable).

My problem is that i have function that in some places in the code exists calls to this function in some versions (this function without strictly API and i can't change it). And now I want to use this function with only one argument (that in the another calls "the first argument" might be another thing) so i want to analyze in this function if I am in this case that i work about or not (so i thought about this way, that I will check in the function via which variable the value passed).

For examples, in some places exists the following calls to this function:

```
a=`func 1 3`
b=`func`
```

But basically, until now, `func` did not get input (according to the API of this function) , but i does not want to touch this places. but, i want pass only one argument to this function and that the function `func` will work in accordance (and to know how to ignore the calls above - while the input is not really valid input).
and in `func` i want to use $1 only in the case that it's valid input and not in the dirty cases that uses this function (in this cases i want to ignore the input)

Comment: No. If `a` contains `17` then given `func ${a}` the shell expands `a` first and the function only sees `func 17`. If you [edit] your question to explain WHAT you're trying to do instead of asking about HOW you think you could implement it then we could help more.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the parameter isn't involved in the call. The shell expands the parameter first, *then* calls the function with the resulting value(s).

Comment: Why does your function need a parameter name in the first place?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input, expected output and code in your question. Right now it's extremely hard to figure out what it is you're trying to do from the description. It sounds like you have a function that takes N arguments and does X, and now you need to have a function that does Y and have decided to re-use the existing function to also do Y and have it test the name of the variable used by the caller do decide if it should do X or Y. That would break both cohesion and coupling so if that is what you're thinking - don't do it.

Comment: Again, please create and post a [mcve] (i.e. with a minimal working script that demonstrates your needs), not just 2 standalone function calls, in your question so we can help you.

Comment: When you create a function (or any other software entity), the most fundamental measure of how "good" is it is that it must be tightly cohesive (does 1 thing only) and loosely coupled to the rest of the code (so the callers/called code and this function can all be changed independently of each other). You seem to be proposing that the function do different things (not be tightly cohesive) based on values in the calling function (be tightly coupled to the caller), i.e. instead of tightly cohesive and loosely coupled (good) be loosely cohesive and tightly coupled (very bad).

Comment: So, we know you should not do what you're asking HOW to do but so far we don't know WHAT you're trying to do and so can't suggest the right approach to do that.

Comment: I described it in my question - i have a function that in some places call to this function with params, but according to the API of the function, this function does not get arguments. All of this was until now. But now, I want to change the function that will get one argument. And i can't touch in the other calls to this function. So how can i write the function so that will treat the case that i pass a valid argument and ignore the other cases that passed invalid arguments..

Answer (score 0):

With **bash** you don't pass parameter names, but only parameters values.

To accomplish this you should add a second parameter which describe the so called "parameter name":

```bash
func {
  echo "The value of '$1' is '$2'."
}

func "a", ${a}
```

Comment: you can pass parameter names. google bash pass by reference (or similar).

Comment: i know that i don't pass the parameter name, but my question is if i can to extract it from some place (while i in the function

Comment: @EdMorton Can you explain it with answer please ?

Comment: @StudentOrint I could but it's not what you asked about. You can't do what you asked about since the function never sees the variable, the shell expands it before the function is called.